# How to call linux command on Jmeter

Tags: linux, jmeter

How to trigger linux command on Jmeter?

Linux command: `cd /var/lib/jenkins/tmp && ./getHMAC.sh -p Floating@2022 -i qa3-appliance.net /kotoba/rest/operationalgroup`

[image]

I tried to use OS Process Sampler but I can't make it work.

Syntax I used:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Error Message

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be the case `bash` is not installed on the machine where you're trying to run your script. Try [`/bin/sh`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141928/what-is-the-difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash) command instead
2. You don't need to do [`cd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) to the `/var/lib/jenkins/tmp` folder given you provided it as a "Working Directory", you can remove any of these options
3. I don't think running a shell script is a good idea at all because it's slow due to invoking a shell interpreter and you're depending on an external .sh script so you won't be able to run your script on Windows or on another machine which doesn't have this .sh script. It might be a better idea to perform the encryption using [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), see [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy) article for more details.